# Leave page for links like Google and Facebook

Tags: hyperlink

When I search in Google and moving the mouse over links I see the link of the current page like in this picture :

[image]

But when I open this link and stop page loading to see the URL I find this

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFsQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.stackoverflow.com%2F&rct=j&q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&ei=gbHqTaa-BcTGtAaRwcjnCg&usg=AFQjCNG7KphjK6RuC5cj-6U5jeuvipt5dg&cad=rja

It's used by Google to sotre data about visitors of this link or when a user copy the link he'll get just the right URL .

The same thing with Facebook for external links ( l.php )

This option help user to see the whole address.

I like to use it in my website so how can I do ??

Comment: "or when a user copy the link he'll get just the right URL" : instead of having the right URL, he has a URL to the right URL. Yeepee!

Comment: what on god's green earth are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how if works in IE. I did not try other browsers, it is possible they are using the same or similar method.

The sample below illustrates what happens:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    window.rwt=function(a,url) {
        a.href=url;
        a.onmousedown="";
    };
})();
</script>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onmousedown="return rwt(this, 'http://www.google.com/')">Stack Overflow</a>
```

The link here points to http://stackoverflow.com, and when you hover mouse over it, it displays http://stackoverflow.com as a target of the link. When you click on the link, instead it brings you to http://www.google.com, because that piece of javascript overrides the `href` attribute.